About the proof of: If $f$ has a non-zero constant term, then $f$ has an inverse as a power series.

Definition: Let $f=\sum a_nT^n$ be a power series. We say that $g=\sum b_nT^n$ is an inverse for $f$ if $fg=1$.

If $fg=1$, then $order(f)=order(g)=0$.  The converse is also true:

Let $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n. $If $f$ has a non-zero constant term, then $f$ has an inverse as a power series.

Proof
Considering $a_0^{-1}f$ instead of $f=\sum a_nf^n$. The geometric series gives us a formal inverse $$\frac{1}{1-r}=1+r+r^2+\cdots$$Thus,\begin{align*} (1-r)(1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots)&=1+r+r^2+\cdots-r(1+r+r^2+\cdots)\\&=1+r+r^2+\cdots-r-r^2-\cdots\\&=1
\end{align*}
Next, write $f=1-h$ where $h=-(a_1T+a_2T^2+\cdots)$, we define $$\varphi=1+h+h^2+h^3+\cdots$$
Consider the finite sum $$1+h+h^2+\cdots+h^m$$ If $m>n$, then with the fact that $h^m$ has order at least $m$, because $h^n$ is of the form $$(-1)^na_1^nT^n+\text{higher terms}$$ we find that $h^m$ has all coefficients of order $\leq n$ equal to $0$. For any $m$, we can write $$\varphi=\sum_{n=0}^mh^n+R_m$$ where $ord(R_m)\geq m+1$. Then $$f\varphi=f\sum_{n=0}^{m}h^n+fR_m=1-h^{m+1}+(1-h)R_m=1+\text{a power series of arbitrarily high order} $$
For $h^{m+1}$ and $R_m$, they all have order at least $m+1$. Since this holds for any $m$, one has $f\varphi=1$.
Question
This is a proposition from Serge Lang's Complex Analysis, it's evident that $(1-h)(1+h+h^2+h^3+\cdots)=1$. I don't understand why we need to consider the finite sum and $R_m$(more rigorous? but why). Also for the last sentence, why it holds for any $m$ can imply $f\varphi=1$? Thank you for your help.

can you give precise statement and the proof? seems there are some missing arguments.

@Needmoremath Updated.

It might help to clear up if you are talking about a multiplicative inverse (reciprocal) or an inverse function. The title suggests the latter but the proof suggests the former.

@Nic Thank you for your comment, updated now.

I rewrite the solution for readability and completeness. Please check if interested!

Formal power series. This theorem deals with formal power series, which are algebraic rather than analytic objects. In this context, a power series is simply a complex sequence with multiplication defined by the Cauchy product. However, this algebraic perspective is also helpful in analysis since any properties established for the "formal" power series must also hold when the series has an analytical meaning.
Geometric series identity. This is valid for a complex value $ r $ with a magnitude less than 1. We can define similar things on formal power series (or sequences equivalently) since $(1,1,\ldots,1,\ldots)$ and $(1, -1, 0, 0,\ldots)$ are inversely related. That is,
$$
(1,1,\ldots,1,\ldots) \ast (1, -1, 0, 0,\ldots) = (1,0,0,\ldots) = e_0\,,
$$
where $\ast$ is the Cauchy product, and $e_0$ is the multiplicative identity on the sequence ring equipped with the Cauchy product (indeed, PID).
Why is the statement not obvious?. Considering the formal power series $h$ as a sequence $(h_n)$ where:
$$
h_0 = 0, h_1 = -\frac{a_1}{a_0}, h_2 = -\frac{a_2}{a_0}, \ldots \,
$$
Now, you can see that
it is not immediately obvious that the sequence $( f_n )$ and $(\varphi_n$) defined by
$$
(f_n): = (e_0) - (h_n) \:\:\text{and}\:\: (\varphi_n) := (e_0) + (h_n) + (h_n) \ast (h_n) + (h_n)^{3\ast} + \ldots \tag{1} 
$$
that represent the formal power series $ f $ and $\varphi$ given are inversely related. Here, $(h_n)^{*m}$ represents $m-1$ Cauchy product operations.
How to show the inverse relationship?.
This inverse relationship can be easily verified using the argument from the given text. Let $ (\varphi_n^m) $ be the sequence defined by taking the first $ m $ terms in the summation that defines $ (\varphi_n) $. Then:
$$
(f_n) \ast (\varphi_n^m) = (e_0) + (h_n) + \cdots + (h_n)^{*(m-1)} - \left[ (h_n) + \cdots + (h_n)^{*m} \right] = (e_0) - (h_n)^{*m},
$$
since $ (e_0) $ is the multiplicative (Cauchy product) identity.
Because the terms $ (h_n)^{*m'} $ for $ m' \geq m $ are only nonzero starting from the $ (m+1) $-th index, we can conclude that $(f_n) \ast (\varphi_n^m) $ equals $ (e_0) $ for the first $ m $ indices. Check the below Addendum for this argument and the well-definedness of $(\varphi_n)$.
Furthermore, by a similar argument, $ (\varphi_n^m) $ and $ (\varphi_n) $ are equal for the first $ m $ indices. Considering the definition of the Cauchy product, it follows that $ (f_n) \ast (\varphi_n) $, $ (f_n) \ast (\varphi_n^m) $, and $ (e_0) $ are all equal for the first $ m $ indices.
Now, since $m$ can be arbitrary, we can conclude that $ (f_n) \ast (\varphi_n)  = (e_0)$.

Addendum
Stating the expression $(1)$ needs careful explanation. The delicate part is that the summation for each index from $(1)$ can be infinite. However, it never happens here. That is, every summation for each index is finite.
It is essential to note that $h_0=0$ to provide the sequence $(\varphi_n)$ (or formal series) is well defined. This directly gives that the summation for index $m$ is at most consists of the first $m$ terms in $(1)$, which are nonzero only from the $m$-th index.
Anyway, IMHO, a rigorous approach should first clarify what expression $(1)$ is without infinite expression.
